# Get filtered elements from an Object

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I want to get the value associated with the condition "Color" defined in var A.

I'm getting the keys of the object, but I want to get the value associated with the condition "Color"

```
function TestOBJ(){

var A = [
  [['apple'],'red'],
  [['tomatoes','strawberry'],'red'],
  [['sky', 'deep sea'],'blue'],
  [['frog'],'green']
  ]

 var dataOBJ={};
 for(var j=0;j<A.length;j++){  
    dataOBJ[j]= {
    CONTENT: A[j][0],
     COR: A[j][1]
  }
   }

Logger.log(dataOBJ);

const filtered = Object.keys(dataOBJ)
               .filter(function esSuficientementeGrande(elemento) {
                 //Logger.log(dataOBJ[elemento].CONTENT[0]);
                 if( dataOBJ[elemento].COR == 'red'){
                   Logger.log(dataOBJ[elemento].CONTENT);
                   return JSON.stringify(dataOBJ[elemento]);
                    }
               });

 Logger.log(filtered);
```

}

For example:
I expect the results:
apple
tomatoes, strawberry

Comment: Maybe just `[].concat(...A.filter(x => x[1] === 'red').map(x => x[0]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the values by the condition of the color.
- For example, when you give `red` as the condition, you want to retrieve `apple tomatoes, strawberry`.

  - In this case, I thought that you might need `"apple", "tomatoes", "strawberry"`.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Modified script 1:

If your script is modified, how about this modification?

```
function TestOBJ(){
  var A = [
    [['apple'],'red'],
    [['tomatoes','strawberry'],'red'],
    [['sky', 'deep sea'],'blue'],
    [['frog'],'green']
  ]

  var dataOBJ={};
  for(var j=0;j<A.length;j++){
    dataOBJ[j]= {
      CONTENT: A[j][0],
      COR: A[j][1]
    }
  }

  Logger.log(dataOBJ);

  const filtered = Object.keys(dataOBJ)
  .reduce(function(ar, elemento) {
    if (dataOBJ[elemento].COR == 'red') ar = ar.concat(dataOBJ[elemento].CONTENT);
    return ar;
  }, []);

  Logger.log(filtered);
}
```

#### Modified script 2:

As other pattern, how about this?

```
function TestOBJ(){
  var A = [
    [['apple'],'red'],
    [['tomatoes','strawberry'],'red'],
    [['sky', 'deep sea'],'blue'],
    [['frog'],'green']
  ]

  // I modified below script.
  var color = "red";
  var res = A.reduce(function(ar, e) {
    if (e[1] === color) ar = ar.concat(e[0]);
    return ar;
  }, []);
  Logger.log(res);
}
```

#### Result:

```
["apple","tomatoes","strawberry"]
```

#### Reference:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.